# Color of Markerclusters

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to change the color of markerclusters (same color for all clusters). Therefore I included this markerclusteroption:

```
       iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
       childCount = cluster.getChildCount();  
       if (childCount < 1000) {  
       c = 'rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.7);'
       c = 'rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.7);'  
       }    
       return new L.DivIcon({
             html: '<div style=\"background-color:'+c+' \"><span>' +
             childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster',  
             iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
      }"))
```

Without this code the app is running but after including the markers don´t cluster anymore. I used this iconCreateFunction for another script and it worked fine.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)


mydat <- data.table( id=c(1,2,3,4),
                 londd=c(20, 38, 96, 32),
                 latdd=c(60, 56, 30, 31),
                 material=c("stone", "water,sand", "sand", "wood"),
                 application=c("a","b","c","d"))

#Set up ui
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(h5("", width=2),
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId="MatFlag",label=h4("Material"),                                                 
           choices=setNames(object=c("stone","water","sand", "wood"),
                                nm=c("stone", "water", "sand", "wood")),
           ),
           checkboxGroupInput(inputId="AppFlag",label=h4("Application"), 
                              choices=setNames(object=c("a","b","c","d"),
                                               nm=c("a","b","c","d")),
           ),
           position="left"),

#App mainPanel content and styles
mainPanel(fluidRow(leafletOutput(outputId="lmap")))
))

#Set up server
server <- function(input, output){
  #Build leaflet map
  lmap <- leaflet(data=mydat)%>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", 
                 options =providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
  fitBounds(~min(londd), ~min(latdd), ~max(londd), ~max(latdd))

#Filter data
datFilt <- reactive({
if (length(input$MatFlag) == 0) filterName <- 'none'
else filterName <- input$MatFlag

print(filterName)
log_mat <- sapply(filterName, function(x) grepl(x, mydat$material))
log_row <- apply(log_mat, 1, any)
mydat[log_row & application %in% input$AppFlag]
})

#Add markers based on selected flags
observe({
if(nrow(datFilt())==0) {
  print("Nothing selected")
  leafletProxy("lmap") %>%
    clearShapes()}
 else{ #print(paste0("Selected: ", unique(input$InFlags&input$InFlags2)))
  leafletProxy("lmap", data=datFilt()) %>% clearShapes() %>%
    clearMarkerClusters() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(lng=~londd, lat=~latdd,
   clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(),
          weight=3,
          color="#33CC33", opacity=1, fillColor="#FF9900", 
          fillOpacity=0.8) 
 }
})

output$lmap <- renderLeaflet(lmap)
}

#Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with your `reactive` called `datFilt`.

First of all, `ifelse(length(input$MatFlag) == 0, 'none', input$MatFlag)` returned only the first selected item, because of how `ifelse` works:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test

The second issue was the usage of `grepl`, that only takes a single element for the pattern argument, so even if you pass it a character vector, it will only use the first element. Example:

```
grepl(c("stone", "sand"), mydat$material)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#Warning message:
#In grepl(c("stone", "sand"), mydat$material) :
#  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Instead you have to loop over the elements that are to be used as patterns. I chose the `apply` family. The `sapply` expression (see in the code section) constructs a matrix showing which search terms are present in which rows.

```
     stone  sand
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE
```

Then I used the `apply` function to see which rows have a `TRUE` values. e.g: With stone and sand checked in the checkbox input, the first 3 rows should be selected.

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Note: There should be an easier way to do this part, it is just the first one I came up with.

Issue #3 is your `input$AppFlag%in%application`. The object returned by the %in% operator has the length of the first argument, and we need the same length as the number of rows in mydat, so you should use `application %in% input$AppFlag`

See in example:

```
c("a", "d") %in% mydat$application
#[1] TRUE TRUE
mydat$application %in% c("a", "d")
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**Working code**:

```
datFilt <- reactive({
    if (length(input$MatFlag) == 0) filterName <- 'none'
    else filterName <- input$MatFlag

    print(filterName)
    log_mat <- sapply(filterName, function(x) grepl(x, mydat$material))
    log_row <- apply(log_mat, 1, any)
    mydat[log_row & application %in% input$AppFlag]
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for solving some problems of my code. Now I edited the code and everything works fine, as long as I am not using "iconcreatefunction".

Comment: Do you know why iconcreatefunction cannot be used in this code?
When I use it, the clustering does not work at all.